# Google calendar automation

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, automation

I'm in the process of writing an MVC (C#) application.

I would like the application to add events to a user's Google calendar. I've had a very quick play and managed to access a Google calendar from a console app, and it seems quite straight forward.

However, the MVC web app will need to manipulate a user's Google calendar when the **user is not logged in**. Is this possible?

Many thanks.

FT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, accessing the calendar directly while not logged in would seem impossible to me. But, if you make a web app/service out of your app that publishes a stream of calendar events (.ics) as a URL, your user could add your calendar as an "Other calendar" referencing your URL and you could publish/modify events through that. Does that make any sense for your use case?

Comment: Awesome suggestion. I've implemented it and it works a treat! Nice one. THANK YOU!